# Is there better way to build one cpp which is in Makefile project?

Tags: makefile

I have one huge makefile-based project. 
I download it from git and modify some .cpp files.
I want to just build those files I modifyed.

Now I think I can use make -n |grep  > build.sh then run the build.sh.

Is there better way ? Thanks.

Comment: You can type `make one.o` to compile `one.cpp` into an object file; you can type `make one` to convert the file into an executable, if that's the expected usage.  If, however, `one.o` goes into a library, simply compiling it to an object file isn't enough. And if you've disturbed the dependencies of already compiled code, those need to be recompiled.  Normally, you would run `make one.o` until you're satisfied it is building OK, and then you'd run `make` or `make all` to let everything catch up with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about how your makefile works there's not much definitive we can say.

If you just want to rebuild `foo.cpp`, you should be able to run `make foo.o`.  But of course, this depends on how complex your makefiles are, whether they're recursive, whether they build the object file in a different directory, etc.